# Need to convert the rows in excel to two fixed columns in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, ssis

Hi I have the following data:

[image]

Now I want to look it like this:

[image]

What is the best way to do it, I have done it using 2D array, but its inefficient and need fixed array size, however, there can be n rows in input file with max of 15 Attribute columns. Can this be achieved with Datatables? I need to push the final version to SQL table using SSIS. I am new to SSIS, if you are aware of any tool in SSIS that can do it, pls let ,me know.

Comment: I have a solution using a script component. Give me aabout 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Starting Point:

[image]

I am basing this on any number of attributes.

Add a script componenet to dataflow(source)

Add your output columns:
[image]

Now enter your script and add this method to read excel into a data table. You already mentioned this so i figured you knew how to do that.

```
public static DataTable exceldata(string filePath)
{
    DataTable dtexcel = new DataTable();
    bool hasHeaders = true;
    string HDR = hasHeaders ? "Yes" : "No";
    string strConn;
    if (filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf('.')).ToLower() == ".xlsx")
        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
    else
        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
    conn.Open();
    DataTable schemaTable = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
    //Looping Total Sheet of Xl File
    /*foreach (DataRow schemaRow in schemaTable.Rows)
    {
    }*/
    //Looping a first Sheet of Xl File
    DataRow schemaRow = schemaTable.Rows[0];
    string sheet = schemaRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    if (!sheet.EndsWith("_"))
    {
        string query = "SELECT  * FROM [" + sheet + "]";
        OleDbDataAdapter daexcel = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
        dtexcel.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        daexcel.Fill(dtexcel);
    }

conn.Close();
return dtexcel;

}
```

Now this is the script for writing out the rows:

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    string filePath = @"D:\Temp\Test.xlsx";
    //string sheetName = "Sheet1" + "_";

    DataTable dt = exceldata(filePath);
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        for (int c = 2; c < dt.Columns.Count; c++)
        {
            if (row[c].ToString() != "")
            {
                Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                Output0Buffer.ID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Field<double>(0));
                Output0Buffer.Name = row[1].ToString();
                Output0Buffer.Attribute = dt.Columns[c].ColumnName;
                Output0Buffer.Value = row[c].ToString();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]